# Nomin Mapper Framework for Groovy

Tags: spring, groovy, mapping, nomin

I am looking for a mapping framework for my Spring/Groovy application. I found [Nomin](http://nomin.sourceforge.net/) - it looks like something that fits my need. But I have the following issue: it doesn't find my mapping rules script in my test class.

in *src/main/groovy/mypackage/entity2entitydto.groovy*:

```
import org.nomin.entity.*

mappingFor a: Entity,  b: EntityDto
a.name      =       b.name
```

in *src/test/groovy/mypackage/Entity2EntityDtoTest.groovy*:

```
public class CoinMarketCap2CoinTest {
    NominMapper nomin = new Nomin("entity2entitydto.groovy");

    // also tried entity2entitydto, Entity2entitydto, Entity2entitydto.groovy
    // also tried with full package name
    // also tried File Name Entity2entitydto.groovy

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // Testing ...
    }

}
```

Result after `gradle clean build --stacktrace`

```
org.nomin.core.NominException: Specified resource entity2entitydto.groovy isn't found!
...
```

Someone any idea or suggestions about mapping frameworks which works fine with groovy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nomin throws this exception, because your script is not in the classpath. Move your `entity2entitydto.groovy` file to `src/main/resources` so Nomin can load your mapping script from the classpath correctly.

Secondly, make sure you import correct classes in your mapping script. For example, if I have `mypackage.Entity` and `mypackage.EntityDto` class then I can import both of them like:

```
import mypackage.Entity
import mypackage.EntityDto

mappingFor a: Entity,  b: EntityDto
a.name      =       b.name
```

Instead you have to use full canonical names like:

```
mappingFor a: mypackage.Entity,  b: mypackage.EntityDto
a.name      =       b.name
```

You can also take a look at this very basic and simple example created basing on your question - https://github.com/wololock/nomin-example

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example and explanation. I checked out your project and it works fine. When I copy your classes into my project then I get same issue as I have... But I know now how the files needs to be organized and need to find the root cause of my problem.

Comment: Do you still face this `Specified resource entity2entitydto.groovy isn't found!` error? Have you copied `entity2entitydto.groovy` to `src/main/resources/entity2entitydto.groovy`?

Comment: I copied your files in exactly same folder than in my project, and then I get same error. The difference between your project and my is, that I am using gradle instead of maven ....

Comment: if you like check it out, it is just a mini project:
https://github.com/MichaelHegner/CCM

You will also find your classes there

Comment: Oh, I just see on console it works already, it seems to be an Eclipse issue. When running the tests on Eclipse I still have the issue ... But thank you, your project helped a lot

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help you :)

Comment: Hi Szymon, in case you have a deep understanding in Nomin, I would highly appreciate you could have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48234524/nomin-mapper-automap-causes-nominexception-inifite-loop